# Clean url to prevent attack due to CR LF

Tags: java, security

I see this code in my application. Can someone please help me understand how this is helping to sanitize request URL to prevent any attack due to CR/LF?

```
public static String validaterequestURL(String requestURL) throws EncodingException {
    Encoder encoder = new DefaultEncoder(new ArrayList<String>());
    //canonicalize
    String clean = encoder.canonicalize(requestURL).trim();
    clean = encoder.decodeFromrequestURL(clean);        
    int idxR = clean.indexOf('\r');
    int idxN = clean.indexOf('\n');
    if(idxN >= 0 || idxR>=0){
        if(idxN>idxR){            
          clean = clean.substring(0,idxN-1);
        }
        else{            
         clean = clean.substring(0,idxR-1);
        }
    }       
    return clean;
}
```

I would particularly like to understand how the below lines work?

```
int idxR = clean.indexOf('\r');
    int idxN = clean.indexOf('\n');
    if(idxN >= 0 || idxR>=0){
        if(idxN>idxR){            
          clean = clean.substring(0,idxN-1);
        }
        else{            
         clean = clean.substring(0,idxR-1);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a `\n` (linefeed/newline) or `\r` (carriage return) character exists, the corresponding index (its position in the string) will be >=0. If so, the `substring` operation truncates the string, removing the offending character and everything after it.

The logic seems to be set up so that if *both* `\n` and `\r` are found, only the later of the two (and anything after it) will be removed. I have no idea why the author thought that was a good idea; I would have expected truncation to be done from the earlier one.